# Italicize a part of a ggplot title while displaying it on two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

To italicize a few words of my ggplot title, I found the package `mdthemes` pretty useful. However, the title are sometimes too long to fit on one line only, so that it requires to be splitted on two. I usually do so by using `\n` where I want it to be splitted, but it doesn't work while using markdown. Is there any other way to separate the title ? Or would it be more manageable with another method than `mdthemes` ?
Note : I also tried with `str_wrap()` from the package `stringr`, but it also didn't work out.

Here is the code I used.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mdthemes)

data(iris)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title ="Sepal length (cm) of *setosa, versicolor, virginica* \n exposed to different treatments") +
  theme_classic() +                                     
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12))
p +  md_theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a html line break `<br>` instead of `\n`, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# install.packages("mdthemes")
library(mdthemes)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title = "Sepal length (cm) of *setosa*, *versicolor*, *virginica* <br> exposed to different treatments") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12)) +
  md_theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Also, I use Claus Wilke's excellent [ggtext package](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/index.html) for this type of thing and I highly recommend it for anything 'complicated', e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title = "Sepal length (cm) of *setosa*, *versicolor*, *virginica* <br> exposed to different treatments") +
  theme_classic() +                                     
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(),
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Further examples of customisation options:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title = "Sepal length (cm) of *setosa*, *versicolor*, *virginica* <br> exposed to different treatments") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.title = element_markdown(halign = 0.5))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title = "Sepal length (cm) of *setosa*, *versicolor*, *virginica* <br> exposed to different treatments") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.title = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5, halign = 0))
```

[image]

```r
color_palette <- scales::hue_pal()(3)
color_palette
#> [1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF"
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +     
  geom_boxplot(show.legend=FALSE, outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Species), alpha = 0.8) +               
  labs(title = "Sepal length (cm) of
       <span style='color:#F8766D'>*setosa*</span>,
       <span style='color:#00BA38'>*versicolor*</span>,
       <span style='color:#619CFF'>*virginica*</span><br>
       exposed to different treatments") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.title = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5, size = 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: As an explanation why we have to use `<br>` you could add that `mdthemes` adds *support for rendering text as markdown* by replacing `element_text` with `ggtext::element_markdown` under the hood for all supported themes.

Comment: It works well, but is it possible to get the second part of the title centered like in the other answer below ?

Comment: Sure - you can customise the text in lots of different ways - I'll edit my answer with an example @chiliconcarno

Answer (score 1):

You can use `atop` . Here is the sample code:

```
  labs(title = expression(atop("Sepal length (cm) of" ~ italic("setosa, versicolor, virginica"), "exposed to different treatments"))) +
```

Here is the sample output:
[image]

You can run [my sample code here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6mtgk7nufE3)